# Java Entity: Either manually setId or autogenerate from sequence

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, micronaut

I have an entity with a composite key using @IdClass as following:

```
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@IdClass(MyId.class)
@SequenceGenerator(
        name = "My_SEQUENCE",
        initialValue = 1,
        allocationSize = 1
)
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "MY_SEQUENCE",
            strategy = "StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "1"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, value = "ABC"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, value = "%07d") })
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "MY_SEQUENCE")
    private String reqId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "rev_no")
    private Long revisionNumber;

...
}
```

And, it's repository as:

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
}
```

And on my service I want following:

```
public class MyEntityService extends BaseService<MyEntityRepository, MyEntity, Long> {
@Transactional
    public MyEntity create(Payload payload) {
        ...
        myEntity.setRevisionNumber(1);
        myEntityRepository.save(myEntity);
        ...
    }

    public MyEntity update(String reqId, Long revisionNumber, Payload payload) {
        var myEntity = findByIdAndRevisionNumber(reqId, revisionNumber);
        ...
        
        myEntity.setRevisionNumber(revisionNumber + 1);
        myEntity.setReqId(reqId);
    
        myEntityRepository.save(myEntity);
}
```

I have two cases:

1. On create, Auto-generate reqId using sequence defined in Entity.
2. On update, increment revision number manually and save new entity with the same reqId.

For case 1, it's working fine but on case#2 it's overriding reqId with auto-generated sequence.

Is there any way to setId manually so that generator won't override it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `GenerationType.IDENTITY`, you won't be able to use setters for particular attribute. It won't work.